# Converting list to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to convert an array of strings to a `DataGridView` with little success so far. The method below is called for that purpose, but it doesn't seem to return any table.

While debugging I can see that I fetch the correct values from `cont.GetAllEmployee()` but when the debug goes to `ConvertListToDataTable(list)` the debugging does not show that method which is something unusual.

This is my current code :

```
private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<WindowsFormsApplication1.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString> list)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        List<string> columnNames = list[0];


        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
        {

            table.Columns.Add(columnNames[i].ToString());
        }

        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(array);
        }

        return table;

    }


List <WindowsFormsApplication1.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString> list = cont.GetAllEmployee();

                   dataGridView.DataSource = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
```

Comment: Why you want to convert the list to a DataTable?  I think you can use the list as data source without converting it.

Comment: No you are not trying to convert to DataGridView.  You are trying to return a Table.  Are you sure you are debugging that method?

Comment: Check that `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns == true`

Comment: Then if your code is inside `Form.Load` event handler, then it possible that you get error inside your function. If so, then put code  of eventhandler inside Try.. Catch block

Comment: DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns == true solved the problem. Gracias Fabio!!

Answer (score -1):

New rows must be instanciated by DataTable.NewRow() method to obtain new DataRow with the same scheme as DataTable.

```
  private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<WindowsFormsApplication1.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString> list)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            List<string> columnNames = list[0];


        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
        {

            table.Columns.Add(columnNames[i].ToString());
        }

        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            var NewRow = table.NewRow();
            for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count)
            {
                NewRow[columnNames[i]] = array[i];
            }
            table.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }

        return table;

    }


    List <WindowsFormsApplication1.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString> list = cont.GetAllEmployee();
                   dataGridView.DataSource = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
                   dataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: It does not seem to solve the problem, the method still does not manage to populate the DataGridView

Comment: Method works fine. You can check in debug the content of  DataTable returned. You need to call dataGrdiView.DataBind(). Automatically binding performed only when specified DataSourceID, not DataSource property. In all other cases you must explicitly call DataBind().

Comment: where should I call DataBind?

Comment: Right after dataGridView.DataSource = ConvertListToDataTable(list);    I already update my answer. Check code, please.

Comment: @Eldar you talking about ASP.NET DataGrid. Winforms `DataGridView` have not `.DataBind()` method

Comment: @Eldar, DataBind gets error message: System.Windows.DataGridView does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' acception a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Form.DataGridView' could be found

Comment: Sorry, I was ambigious. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx)                         This article explains binding routine for the WinForms. I am not familiar with this routine. I don't think that there is need to minus my reputation for the help efforts. btw Hope this help.

Comment: I was put minus on reputation of your answer only because, this wasn't about right approach(different framework). I was hoped you will change your answer.